# Dynamically allocated array won't print outside the function it's declared

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This program will scan a PGM file and store it's values to an array dynamically allocated `img` inside the function `LerPGM()`, the function will then return `&img`. As I declared `PGM *imgconv`I assign `LerPGM`to it (`imgconv=LerPGM()`). The thing is, the `printf`inside the function (`printf("%d ", img.imagem[i][j])` works perfectly, but the `printf("%d ", imgconv->imagem[i][j])` inside the `main()` only prints the first item and then the program stops working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int c;
    int l;
    unsigned char maximo;
    unsigned char **imagem;
} PGM;

PGM *LerPGM(char* entrada);

int main()
{
    PGM *imgconv;
    int i, j;

    imgconv=LerPGM("entrada.pgm");
    for(i=0; i<imgconv->l; i++){
        for(j=0; j<imgconv->c; j++){
            printf("%d ", imgconv->imagem[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

PGM *LerPGM(char* entrada){
    PGM img;
    char tipo[3];
    int i, j;

    FILE *arq;
    arq = fopen(entrada, "r");
    if(arq == NULL){
        printf("Arquivo nao encontrado.");
        return 0;
    }

    fscanf(arq, "%s %d %d %d", &tipo, &img.c, &img.l, &img.maximo);
    if(strcmp(tipo, "P2")){
        printf("O arquivo nao e PGM.");
        return 0;
    }

    img.imagem = malloc(img.l * sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0; i<img.c; i++) img.imagem[i] = malloc(img.c * sizeof(char));
    if(img.imagem == NULL){
        printf("Falha na alocacao de memoria.");
        return 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<img.l; i++){
        for(j=0; j<img.c; j++){
            fscanf(arq, "%d", &img.imagem[i][j]);
        }
    }

    fclose(arq);

    for(i=0; i<img.l; i++){
        for(j=0; j<img.c; j++){
            printf("%d ", img.imagem[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return &img;
}
```

Comment: It's been a long time since encountering this instance of undefined behavior on SO...

Comment: Why do you think `img` is dynamically allocated? It's a local variable. Dynamic allocation is done using `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a pointer from a function, but the data was on the stack.   That is why it doesn't work.

```
  X * func() {
      X data;

      return &data; /* <<== this is broken. */

  }
```

When `func` in my case, or `LerPGM` return, the data from the stack in the function is destroyed.

Fix - something like ...

```
PGM *LerPGM(char* entrada){
    PGM * img = (PGM*)malloc( sizeof( PGM ) );
    char tipo[3];
    int i, j;

    FILE *arq;
    arq = fopen(entrada, "r");
    if(arq == NULL){
        printf("Arquivo nao encontrado.");
        return 0;
    }

    fscanf(arq, "%s %d %d %d", &tipo, &img->c, &img->l, &img->maximo);
    if(strcmp(tipo, "P2")){
        printf("O arquivo nao e PGM.");
        return 0;
    }

    img->imagem = malloc(img->l * sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0; i<img->c; i++) img->imagem[i] = malloc(img->c * sizeof(char));
    if(img->imagem == NULL){
        printf("Falha na alocacao de memoria.");
        return 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<img->l; i++){
        for(j=0; j<img->c; j++){
            fscanf(arq, "%d", &img->imagem[i][j]);
        }
    }

    fclose(arq);

    for(i=0; i<img->l; i++){
        for(j=0; j<img->c; j++){
            printf("%d ", img->imagem[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return img;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to http://pastebin.com/cvxya2yW and it seems to work now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a pointer to a **local** variable. That is a pointer to a variable, which gets *destroyed* and disappears on the return. After the return the place pointed may contain some other data, unrelated to the previous content of the `img` variable.

If you want to return data from the function, you should either prepare the variable outside the function and pass it to the function for filling:

```
int LerPGM(char* entrada, PGM *img){
    // ....

    FILE *arq = fopen(entrada, "r");
    if(arq == NULL){
        printf("Arquivo nao encontrado.");
        return 0;  // ERROR
    }

    // ....
    return 1;    // SUCCESS
}

int main()
{
    PGM imgconv;
    int i, j;

    if( LerPGM("entrada.pgm", &imgconv) ) {
        for(i=0; i<imgconv->l; i++){
            for(j=0; j<imgconv->c; j++){
                printf("%d ", imgconv->imagem[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else
        printf("No data to process.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

or allocate a new variable on a heap inside the function and return a pointer to it (then remember to release the variable after use):

```
PGM *LerPGM(char* entrada){
    PGM *img = NULL;
    // ....

    FILE *arq = fopen(entrada, "r");
    if(arq == NULL){
        printf("Arquivo nao encontrado.");
        return NULL;  // ERROR
    }

    // ....
    img = malloc(sizeof(PGM));
    if(img != NULL)
    {
        // fill variable *img with data
    }

    return img;
}

int main()
{
    PGM* imgconv;
    int i, j;

    // ...
    imgconv = LerPGM("entrada.pgm");
    if(imgconv != NULL) {
        for(i=0; i<imgconv->l; i++){
            for(j=0; j<imgconv->c; j++){
                printf("%d ", imgconv->imagem[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        free(imgconv->subcomponents);
        free(imgconv);
    }
    else
        printf("No data to process.\n");

    return 0;
}
```